# MSSQL 2008 - Id like to divide one select by another

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Both selects result in a number.

But, I can't seem to divide one by another.

Expecting output to be ~9%

Code:

```
select

(select count(b.booking_id) from booking b where b.pickup_date > '01 feb 2014' and b.pickup_date < '01 mar 2014')

/

(select count(q.quote_id) from quoting q where q.pickup_date > '01 feb 2014' and q.pickup_date < '01 mar 2014')
```

Comment: what are the results of each select statement?

Comment: first is ~50k - second is ~550k

Comment: yup, when you use count() sql server returns that as an integer and does integer math, you need to cast as a numeric/decimal/float something with a precision element to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select CAST(A.X AS NUMERIC)/ CAST(NULLIF(B.Y, 0) AS NUMERIC)
FROM
(select count(b.booking_id) AS X 
from booking b 
where b.pickup_date > '01 feb 2014' 
and b.pickup_date < '01 mar 2014') A
,
(select count(q.quote_id) AS Y 
from quoting q 
where q.pickup_date > '01 feb 2014' 
and q.pickup_date < '01 mar 2014') B
```

The reason you always get Zero is

```
SELECT (50000 /550000)
```

The both passed values are INT and returned value is also INT, No data type is being converted.

But if you were to do as follows

```
SELECT CAST(50000 AS NUMERIC)/ CAST(550000 AS NUMERIC)
```

OR even

```
SELECT (50000 /550000.12121212)
```

You will get the correct results. The reason is in First query you are doing an explicit conversion to datatype Numeric .

In Second Query Sql Server does an implicit conversion for you from INT to DECIMAL because of Data Type Precedence. Read here to learn more about [`Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

Comment: @gh9 have a look now I forgot to cast it as numeric to get the decimal digits :)

Comment: you really busted your hump on this one. If I had another upvote I would give it to you. This should be marked as the answer because it is the most infromative

Comment: lol "Busted my hump" , Well there is a Chinese saying "Teach him how to catch a fish rather than giving him a fish". If the OP knows why he couldnt get the expect results it will help him in the future as well with other similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using Integers select is doing integer math. 
You will need to cast the count statements to doubles in order to get a result when the case of 2/4 happens, and check for nulls

PSEUDO CODE

```
SELECT CAST(A AS DECIMAL(13,5) / nullif(CAST (B AS DECIMAL(13,5), 0.0)
```

Comment: It won't seem to let me to.. Cast((selectquery) as double) - Throws an error - Is this syntax issues my end?

Comment: whomever downvoted please leave a comment as why. Everything that I stated is factually correct

Comment: When selects are pasted in replacing A and B I get errors on syntax? RE: SELECT CAST(A AS DECIMAL(13,5) / nullif(CAST (B AS DECIMAL(13,5), 0.0)